# Understanding the OctoberCMS Task Scheduler

Tags: plugins, components, scheduled-tasks, octobercms

Right now I have the task scheduler to ping, with a query string for authentication, a page that runs a php function from a component onRun(). So of course my task scheduler looks something like this:

```
public function registerSchedule($schedule)
{
    $url = 'https://domain/page/dosomething?v=some&p=secret';
    $schedule->command('foo')
        ->cron('12 * * * *')
        ->pingBefore($url);
}
```

This leads to every 12 minutes on the hour an error is created in the logs because I don't have a command for 'foo'. I tried to use the exec method but it didn't seem to ever run my code no matter how I worded the functions.

I created this to keep the connection live with Quickbooks Online API instead of having the server check the access token and refreshing the token per user actions. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: You could have a lot of things wrong with your code. Did you properly register your custom console command you're trying to call with `command()`? Do you have a typo? Did you try running `exec('php artisan yourcommandhere')` instead? How about just running your code directly inside of a closure passed to `call()`? https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/scheduling#defining-schedules

Comment: @LukeTowers Thanks for your reply. I will attempt again to run the code inside a closure passed to call(). To clarify I am just using this task to ping the page and this works fine. Not for the command('foo') and it works as is. I was just seeing if there was a way to ping a url without call exec or command().